# how to make working custom dictionary in wpf richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

I've tried to add custom dictionary (*.lex format, utf-16 encode) in RichTextBox to make spellcheck, but it doesn't works. If i using such code for TextBox, it works.

```
private void SpellCheckInit()
{   
    // this works            
    txt_Box.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(new Uri(@"C:\dictionary.lex"));

    // dictionary language is russian, but this setting makes spellcheck works                  
    txt_Box.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-GB");
    txt_Box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;

    // this doesn't works
    richtxt.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(new Uri(@"C:\dictionary.lex"));
    var ruLang = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ru");
    var enLang = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-GB");
    richtxt.Language = ruLang;

    // or richtxt.Language = enLang; there are no difference for working
    richtxt.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true; 
}
```

I've already added #LID1049 in dictionary, but it has no effect.
Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways adding custom dictionaries

The first custom dictionary (customwords.lex) is added in XAML

```
<RichTextBox Margin="38,18,40,0" Name="richTextBox1" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" >
<SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
    <!-- customwords.lex is included as a content file-->
    <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/customwords.lex</sys:Uri>
</SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
```

and the Second The second custom dictionary (customwords2.lex) is added in the event handler, The file is included as a resource file and compiled into the application assembly that is named WPFCustomDictionary

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IList dictionaries = SpellCheck.GetCustomDictionaries(richTextBox1);
    // customwords2.lex is included as a resource file
    dictionaries.Add(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/WPFCustomDictionary;component/customwords2.lex"));
}
```

Does this works for you???